# after_rollback on :create not triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions

I have a `product` table and  I try to run after_commit and after_rollback on create.

controller:

```
  product = Product.new form_params
  if product.save
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
```

model:

```
  after_commit(on: :create) {
    ...
  }

  after_rollback(on: :create) {
    ...
  }
```

after_commit works well but after_rollback wont work with `on: :create` param. When I remove the `on: :create` param, it triggers too but I need after_rollback to trigger just on create.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to define it differently...

```
  after_commit :after_commit_action, on: :create

  after_rollback :after_rollback_action, on: :create

  def after_commit_action
    # do your magic
  end

  def after_rollback_action
    # do your magic
  end
```

Comment: oh, I see I added some comma's, try again with updated code.

Comment: didn't make change. I don't think it's about syntax cause I don't get any errors but validation or database, it just won't trigger callback when I add the on: :create param.